# MySQL и С++ Как работать :

Tags: c++, mysql

Хочу сделать пет-проект с использование database.
Выбрал MySQL. Вопрос, как добавлять и удалять данные из бд.
Я никогда не работал с бд и не понимаю как работать..
Нагуглил что надо скачивать какие-то доп.приложения, совсем запутался.
Просьба: обьяснить на пальцах, как подключать и добавлять данные в бд.

Comment: Не берите MySQL, возьмите лучше Sqlite3. Он простой как табуретка - скачиваете один `.c` и один `.h` и компилируете их со своим проектом.

Comment: Оу, а можно более детально обьяснить об этом?

Comment: Проще найдите какой-нибудь гайд по нему.

Answer (score 2):

Есть стандарт SQL, его более-менее все придерживаются, так что можно для начала книгу по SQL почитать. Советую эту:
**SQL. Полное рукводство (2015) (Грофф, Вайнберг, Оппель)**

В ней же объясняются варианты взаимодействия с RDBMS через API.

Также стоит прочитать про нормальные формы (NF). Дальше третьей читать особого смысла нет, только ради любопытства если. Это очень пригодятся при проектировании БД.

Ну и, конечно, стоит потренироваться с запросами. Сначала с простыми, затем более сложными, особенно с `SELECT`ами: с `UNION`, с `JOIN`ами и подзапросами.